# Require not defined in nodejs + Angularjs

Tags: javascript, mysql, angularjs, node.js

I have created a server.js file :

```
var express = require('express'); 
var mysql = require('mysql');
var app = express();

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
     host: 'localhost',
     user: 'root',
     password: 'root',
     database: 'test'
});
connection.connect();

app.get('/test', function(req, res, next){
   var query = connection.query('select * from members', function(err, result) {
     if (err) {
       console.error(err);
       return res.send(err);
     } else {
       return res.send('Ok');
     }
  });
});

app.listen(8080);
```

and in my home controller i called the method as:

```
liveApp.controller('HomeCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.getData = function() {
        $http.get('http://localhost:8080/test').success(function(data){
         console.log(data);
        });
    }

    $scope.getData();
}]);
```

I am getting error as Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined at server.js:1

I have done npm install express, npm install mysql. My application is an angular app using yeoman generator.

How can I resolve this issue? My overall objective is to connect to mysql db from angularjs controller.

Comment: how are you running the server?

Comment: I have used grunt serve

Comment: Where exactly do you see that error? In the browser? Did you include server.js in the HTML file by mistake?

Comment: I see this error when i load the view associated with this controller. Yes i have included server.js in index.html

Comment: The server.js file is, as the name suggests, a server-side Node.js script. You're not supposed to run it on the browser.

Comment: Did you find the solution? i have the same problem but i run the server locally using nom start.